# Is there a better approach to handle POST request at controller level?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, post, controller

I have already written following method at controler:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/register")
public String register (@RequestBody HackerUser user) {
    HackerUser newUser = new HackerUser(user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getUsername(), user.getUmuziEmail(), user.getPassword(), user.getRole());
    return service.registerUser(newUser);    
}
```

Could I clarify a few details about above code snippet:

- is it a well-written controller that registers a new user?
- should the model be validated in back-end or front end?

Comment: You don't need to create a new HackerUser, you could have just used the parameter to save (service.registerUser(user)).

Next to that, your methods in Java start with a small letter (NOT "RegisterUser", but "registerUser")

Comment: *should the model be validated in back-end or front end?* Both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might be better to use something like ResponseEntity,

```
@PostMapping(path = "/Register")
public ResponseEntity<HackerUser> Register (@RequestBody HackerUser user) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.RegisterUser(newUser));    
}
```

and your **"RegisterUser"** method can be like:

```
public HackerUser RegisterUser(HackerUser user) {
      HackerUser newUser = new HackerUser(
      user.getFirstName(),
      user.getLastName(),
      user.getUsername(),
      user.getUmuziEmail(),
      user.getPassword(),
      user.getRole());

      return repo.save(newUser);
}
```

Comment: notice that, repo is your repository, and feel free to ask any question

Comment: in Java method's names start from lower case letter.

Comment: @nazar_art you right, sry about that,